# differentiating between articles and nouns

Tags: articles

> The madrigal is polyphonic.
>   **(being polyphonic is characteristic of madrigrals)**
>
> Madrigals are polyphonic.
>   (being polyphonic is normal for madrigrals)
>
> A madrigal is polyphonic.
>   (**being polyphonic is required for madrigrals**)

These are as opposed to

> The madrigal is popular.
>   (being popular is characteristic of madrigrals)
>
> Madrigals are popular.
>   (being popular is normal for madrigrals)
>
> *A madrigal is popular.
>   (**being popular is required for madrigrals)**

... and of course this last conclusion is wrong, producing the star.

Considering the explanations above, the bold part would be incorrect. Nevertheless, I cannot understand the bold parts well. I am really willing to get the red part as a rule of thumb for such a situation so that I could use the article A properly.

In a book it said:"the following is incorrect".

> A computer has revolutionized publishing( **being revolutionized publishing is required for computers)**

My biggest question is only about the following. Would you please help me in a way so that I could use the function below for other situations like those above
?

***being revolutionized publishing is required for computers)***

Comment: Nima, where have you read that the use of **a** means that the mentioned quality **is required** for the subject that takes the indefinite article? *A computer has revolutionized publishing* reads to me as *There was (or still exists) a computer, one computer. It has revolutionized publishing*. Quite a feat for a single computer.

Comment: The article **a** simply designates that you are speaking about a single object out of a group of objects that have the same name, depending on the context it can be used to refer to any one of the objects or a specific unidentified object in that group. "There is a computer that revolutionized publishing." "A computer could revolutionize publishing."

Comment: I am so sorry, as I forgot to write something. So, I have just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the first 2 examples, the last statement is incorrect because it wasn't a single computer(**a**) or a specific computer(**the**) that revolutionized publishing, it was computers as a group. The correct statement would be:

> Computers have revolutionized publishing. (having revolutionized publishing is normal, or a fact for all computers as a group)

"**The**" designates that you are referring to a specific object out of a group of objects.

"**A**" designates that you are referring to any one object out of a group of objects.

> The flat screen is modern technology. (being modern technology is a characteristic of one specific flat screen)
>
> Flat screens are modern technology. (being modern technology is a characteristic of all flat screens)
>
> A flat screen is modern technology. (being modern technology is a characteristic of any single flat screen)

Comment: Thanks. Considering my question above, However, I am having problem with the following. I cannot get it well. And, I am wondering what is its purpose:(being something is required for something reason. Or, why the writer has written it.

Comment: @nima_persian Saying that it's "required" is a bit confusing and may not have been the best word for the writer to use. Using a phrase like "A [x] is [y]." is saying a property or characteristic(y) applies to each object(x) by default, or naturally. It's the same as saying "[y]s are [x]." but in a different way. `A boy is male.` = `Boys are male.` both of these phrases have the exact same meaning with no difference in nuance or connotation.